# How do I make the value of a dictionary constant when passing in a variable multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
original_number = int(input('Please enter a number: '))

all_divisors = {} # lists all of the divisors
b = [1]

# adds 1 to the end of b, then puts it into all_divisors with key
# equal to its divisor, its value is a list of 1's with a number of 1's
# equal to the key
for a in range(2, original_number + 1):
    b.append(1)
    all_divisors[a] = b
    print(all_divisors) # just to make sure everything works properly
```

What I'm trying to do is get a result like:

```
Please enter a number: 4
{2: [1, 1]}
{2: [1, 1], 3: [1, 1, 1]}
{2: [1, 1], 3: [1, 1, 1], 4: [1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

Instead, I get:

```
Please enter a number: 4
{2: [1, 1]}
{2: [1, 1, 1], 3: [1, 1, 1]}
{2: [1, 1, 1, 1], 3: [1, 1, 1, 1], 4: [1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

How do I get each value in the dictionary to be the value of b when it's passed in? (That is the correct use of 'pass in' right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your dictionary values are references to the same list, `b`. Therefor they will be updated when `b` is updated. You need to make a copy of `b` for each key.

```
for a in range(2, original_number + 1):
b.append(1)
all_divisors[a] = b[:]
print(all_divisors)
```

Where `b[:]` is a new list, instead of a reference to the original list `b`

Comment: Does this work with non-lists? The `[:]` part, whatever that's called?

Comment: What do you mean by non-lists?

Answer (score 0):

```
original_number = 4
for i in range(2,original_number+1):
    print dict((j,[1]*j) for j in range(2,i+1))
```

maybe i guess?

but to answer the original question about the original code

```
all_divisors[a] = b[:]
```

should fix the problem